# Check window for focus-Password Generator C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For my end of year project I am creating a password generator where you generate a password, then you can choose whether or not you want to store it in a local compact DB(.sdf). I am working on the GUI at the moment. I am creating a strength bar for passwords but the problem is that I can't seem to have it update the strength bar without first moving the slider. Let me show you example of what I am talking about. I was wondering if I could do this with code or with action events. Tell me what you think. Below is some code for the GUI designer. Do you think this is a good idea or would there be a better way? The focus idea came from if the window has focus it would keep checking the options and see if anything has changed. Video: http://youtu.be/ihSeKbsL55M

```
namespace PasswordGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void quitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void bcopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (passwordGenBox.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(passwordGenBox.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Password Generated.", "Copy Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void bclear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            passwordGenBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void lengthSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sliderLength.Text = lengthSlider.Value.ToString();
            int str = lengthSlider.Value;
            bool scheck = symCheck.Checked;
            bool ncheck = numbersCheck.Checked;
            //1-10 no symbols or numbers
            if (str > 0 && str <= 10)
            {
                strLabel.Text = "Week";
            }
            //1-10 symbols no numbers
            if (str > 0 && str <= 10 && scheck == true && ncheck == false)
            {
                strLabel.Text = "Alright";
            }
            //1-10 no symbols but numbers
            if (str > 0 && str <= 10 && scheck == false && ncheck == true)
            {
                strLabel.Text = "Week";
            }
            //1-10 symbols & numbers
            if (str > 0 && str <= 10 && scheck == true && ncheck == true)
            {
                strLabel.Text = "Okay";
            }
        }

        private void bgen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pwlength = lengthSlider.Value;
            bool symbols = false;
            bool numbers = false;
            if (symCheck.Checked && numbersCheck.Checked)
            {
                symbols = true;
                numbers = true;
            }
            else if (symCheck.Checked && numbersCheck.Checked == false)
            {
                symbols = true;
                numbers = false;
            }
            else if (symCheck.Checked == false && numbersCheck.Checked)
            {
                symbols = false;
                numbers = true;
            }
            else
            {
                symbols = false;
                numbers = false;
            }
            Generator gen = new Generator(pwlength, symbols, numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're really asking? You said "but the problem is that I can't seem to have it update the strength bar without first moving the slider." But since your code to update the strength is inside the Slider's Scroll event, that seems to make sense that that's when it would update. ??

Comment: Daniel actually answered exactly what I was looking for. I should of just put them in different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's quite difficult to understand what you're actually asking here but the reason your ProgressBar isn't updating is that you're not actually telling it to update unless you move the slider.

Notice how you have all your logic for whether the password is "alright, weak or okay" on the Slide event of your "lengthSlider" component. However, nowhere in that code do you set the value of the ProgressBar - that appears to be done on the "bgen_Click" event which I assume is the generate password button?

In order to update the GUI when you operate the individual controls you need to call the appropriate code. I would suggest you put all your logic into meaningful functions and call them as needed.

Personally I'd have something along these lines:

- GetPasswordStrengthString(); - check for symbols and numbers checkbox.checked and the length to return an appropriate string for the "strLabel" label.
- CalculateStrengthBarLength(); - all your logic to determine the length of the ProgressBar

These would then be called wherever you want them to take effect. For example, on the CheckedChanged event of the symbols and numbers checkboxes as when that changes you want to see it reflected in the ProgressBar.